# Apache permanent redirect goes to www automatically

Tags: apache, redirect

My domain name is example.com without www. So if I put www.example.com then it does not work but example.com works. So I configured apache like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot path/to/project/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/keys/xxx.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/keys/xxx.key
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log combined
    <Directory "path/to/project/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now, as you can see, I do a permanent redirection to https like

```
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/
```

But this redirection add www with the domain name by default. So the redirected url becomes `https://www.example.com/`. Obviously my website can not be accessed from with www  since it is registered without www. So please tell me how can make the redirect to work and go to `https://example.com/` without the https.

Answer (score 0):

**Add an Alias**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This requires that the www.yourdomain.com points to the same place as yourdomain.com. However the www might not work with your SSL certificate, it depends on the certificates specificity.

I generally allow both on my sites as some people insist on including the www whenever they enter an address.

Apache's documentation can help out with more specifics https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

**As far as the redirect issue you're having:**
Make sure you don't have some RewriteEngine rules that are rewriting your non www requests to www. You might have an `.htaccess` file in your site directory that is doing the rewrite/redirect.

It might look something like:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Which would mean you should remove the www in the last Rewrite Rule